# 3d matrix rotation

Tags: matrices, rotations

I've been reading up on [rotation transformation](http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/rotation-transformation.html) and following [this PowerPoint](http://www.cs.csi.cuny.edu/~natacha/TeachSpring_12/CSC470/Notes/Lec11/lec11.pdf).

The assignment I'm working on is asking to perform a rotation and find the image $Q$ of the point `P = (1, 2, -1)` after a $45$ degree $y$-roll. I was under the impression that a roll was on the $z$-axis; which is where I'm confused.

I'm trying to set up the problem like such (from [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)):

[image]

But I'm lost as to translate the 3 points into a matrix. Is this correct? The way I'm trying to visualize it as below without the translation.

[image]

Comment: I think you are reading too much meaning into the word 'roll'. The $y$ coordinate remains unchanged, the $x,z$ coordinates are rotated in the $x,z$ plane by $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Would [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rotation+matrix&a=*C.rotation+matrix-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=45+%C2%B0&x=8&y=6&f=RotationCalculator.alpha_45+%C2%B0&a=*FP.RotationCalculator.dir-_plus&a=*FP.RotationCalculator.axis-_y&a=*FVarOpt.1-_***RotationCalculator.axis--.***RotationCalculator.point---.*--) be an accurate representation?

Comment: Looks good... ${}{}{}$

Comment: I'm with copper.hat about the interpretation of "roll". It seems like it is just referring to "twisting" around a specified axis, and it doesn't prefer any special axis.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about when you mean "three points into a matrix". We've got one point and one transformation matrix. The image of the point under the transformation is again a single point: the image of $P$ under the rotation.

Comment: What are you asking exactly ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it's safe to say this 6 year old question has been answered.

Comment: @Kermit: I know it's been answered, but that doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To roll $\theta=\pi/4$ around the $y$ axis, the matrix becomes:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}/2&0&\sqrt{2}/2\\0&1&0\\-\sqrt{2}/2&0&\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}$$

Applying this to the point:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}/2&0&\sqrt{2}/2\\0&1&0\\-\sqrt{2}/2&0&\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\-\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

So, $Q=(0,2,-\sqrt{2})$

Comment: What I meant in my comment was just what you did in the "applying this point."

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO OK :) Like the name, btw.